# Strange error msg in VBA, Shouldn't come up

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write a simple VBA code to find specific text in a predefined Range and Select Case based on the search string (mykey).

```
Dim min As Integer 
Dim R As Range
Dim month As String

Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").Activate

If mykey.Text <> "" Then   'mykey being a combobox

Select Case mykey.Text
Case Is = "0 deg"
Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").Range("B4:B39").Find(mykey.Text).Activate
Case Is = "30 deg"
Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").Range("B44:B79").Find(mykey.Text).Activate
Case Is = "45 deg"
Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").Range("B84:B119").Find(topothesia.Text).Activate
Case Is = "60 deg"
Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").Range("B124:B159").Find(mykey.Text).Activate
Case Is = "90 deg"
Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").Range("B164:B199").Find(mykey.Text).Activate
End Select
```

Once in a while! when I run the code, I get an error msg saying: 
Object Variable or With Block Variable not set., on the Case statement that handles the selected deg, but this does not come up, every time I run the Code.

6/10 times it does.

Why is this strange thing happening?

Comment: `Case Is = "0 deg"` is awkward, use `Case "0 deg"`. Otherwise the error means `Find` didn't find anything.

Comment: Nop, same thing is happening...

Comment: Is that third case really using a different text source? Ans as GSerg says, the error means something is not there: either topothesia, or there was no range found.

Comment: Look reality is more complicated...
The actual name of the key field, is topothesia, in every Case...

What I was trying to accomplish is moving back and forth through some forms (Wizard Like), so, when I go back to the previous form and than get back to this form, I get the error message...

I suppose some object gets blown up in the process. I dont get the error msg, if I continue pressing "Next".

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (not really answer, but too long to post as a comment, sorry about that):

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").Range("B4:B39").Find(mykey.Text)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Activate
Else
    MsgBox "Nothing found"
End If
```

Adapt this to fit all cases (only one declaration, put the rest in each case and maybe add a different error msg each time). If this still happens without getting a message box with your message then you should come back and tell us more about what you have found.

Comment: Yes, this actually did the trick...

Still I don't get why this was happening. It had to do with some objects not being created normally...

Answer (score 0):

Your find method is not actually finding the correct result.

If you use `Find` and it does *not* find a match it will return that error if you try to do something with the result (like `Activate` in your case) - this likely is because the data in the text box(es) is not matching something in your `B` column.

Try something like this instead:

```
Dim min As Integer 
Dim R As Range
Dim month As String

Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").Activate
dim result as Range
If mykey.Text <> "" Then   'mykey being a combobox

Select Case mykey.Text
Case Is = "0 deg"
    set result = Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").Range("B4:B39").Find(mykey.Text)
Case Is = "30 deg"
    set result = Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").Range("B44:B79").Find(mykey.Text)
Case Is = "45 deg"
    set result = Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").Range("B84:B119").Find(topothesia.Text)
Case Is = "60 deg"
    set result = Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").Range("B124:B159").Find(mykey.Text)
Case Is = "90 deg"
    set result = Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").Range("B164:B199").Find(mykey.Text)
End Select

'notify on a lack of result
if (result is nothing) then
    msgbox( "No successful match found for " & Is & "!")
end if
```

This will help isolate your problem. You may have to somehow verify the `mykey` and `topothesia` textboxes actually have matches in your code or do some validation/error checking (I cannot do the validation for you since I have no idea what your spreadsheet looks like, so I've added error checks :)).